Using bash and managed identities to clone a git repo in the same organsation
I've tried looking for this but can't find the exact answer I'm looking for. I want to clone a git repo in the same AAD backed ADO organisation using a managed identity.
I'm using a pipeline which uses Terraform to deploy a VM, and I want to pass a script into custom_data when I build this VM to clone a repo from my ADO.
I could pass the SYSTEM_ACCESS_TOKEN to the terraform and then use that to clone the repo in the custom_data script but I was wondering if there was a neater way to do it (I'm concerned the token is not secure, which may perhaps be unfounded)


I could pass the SYSTEM_ACCESS_TOKEN to the terraform and then use that to clone the repo in the custom_data script but I was wondering if there was a neater way to do it (I'm concerned the token is not secure, which may perhaps be unfounded)

In fact System access token is more secure than managed identity, it's dynamically generated by Azure Pipelines, and only exists during pipeline run time.
While Managed identity, you need to manage it from Azure portal, but also need to add it to the DevOps organization to grant the permission.
Also, it's more convenient to manage system access token , you can check project scoped identity or collection scoped identity due to your settings, and set the permission directly.
Please check the docs below for your reference:
Access repositories, artifacts, and other resources
About service principals and managed identities

Is that still the case when im deploying custom_data to a vm? the terraform will now have the System access token variable stored in plain text in the state file?

Thanks @Owensteam. The system access token is used to clone the repo only, not need to store it in state file.  To deploy custom_data to vm, you can raise a new ticket, and share minim terraform sample to help for checking.

I'm using the terraform run on the build server to create a vm which then clones a repo using the script in custom_data. I need the repo on the new vm for my own reasons. does this make sense? in this case i have to pass the token to terraform from the pipeline so it can be used in the terraform custom_data script which seems like a security risk in the state file to me?

It makes sense. The system access token only exists during pipeline run time. You could read the value from pipeline and pass to custom_data script to clone the repo. The token   retired after the pipeline, even you store in state file.
